# Validación de formularios en Drupal 8

Tags: formularios, drupal8

Estoy intentando validar un formulario en Drupal. He probado con los siguientes 2 códigos y no me funcionan. Podrían ayudarme con ello? Gracias de antemano !!!

No puse ninguna condición de validación para complicar menos el código y encontrar el problema.

1.

```
<?php

use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function validations_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['#validate'][] = "validate";
}

function validate(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form_state->setErrorByName('Error',t('Error'));
}
```

2. 

```
<?php

use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function validations_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    $form_set_error('Error',t('Error'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucioné el problema, era que faltaba el **&** en el parámetro **$form** y que el primer parámetro esperado por la función **setErrorByName** es el nombre del campo a validar.

Quedando asi:

```
<?php

    function validations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        $form['#validate'][] = "validate";
    }

    function validate(&$form, &$form_state){
        $form_state->setErrorByName('title',t('Error'));
    }
```

Ahora solo queda escribir las condiciones de la validación y listo.